# Convert Julian Date to Normal System Date in Silverlake(USing SQL statement)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, julian-date

I am trying to convert Julian Date to Gregorian/Normal Date(mm/dd/yyyy) in SilverLake DB.

I am using Oracle SQL statements to query SilverLake db. I tried it with:

```
TO_CHAR(<myfieldname>,'YYYYDDD')
```

But SilverLake DB is throwing me an error:

> Argument 1 is not valid for TO_CHAR function

Would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not allowed to post a reply to the previous comment since I am a new user, but this answer also responds there. What you refer to as *SilverLake DB* is actually a specific vendor implementation (*Jack Henry & Associates*) of the *Db2 for i* database, for their *SilverLake* core banking system. This is the database that comes with the **IBM iSeries**, a midrange computer also known with it's older name **AS/400** (think of a mainframe, just smaller). While antiquated this is still used for legacy reasons, especially in banking systems such as *SilverLake*.

*ORACLE* specific commands will NOT work there, other than by coincidence of IBM also using them, and any research you are doing should be referring to **Db2 for i**, I doubt you will find much content for *SilverLake* specifically unless you reach to the vendor directly.

I have had luck with the following statement with what you are trying to do:

```
COGSUP.JDTODATE(<myfieldname>)
```

this will convert the data type to an ISO Date format, in my humble opinion this should be the only date format used on databases.

If you still need to convert this to the American notation for presentation purposes, you can wrap this with a to_char statement:

```
to_char(COGSUP.JDTODATE(<myfieldname>), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `to_date()` to turn the julian date to a `date`:

```
to_date(col, 'j')
```

Then if you need to represent the date in a given format, you can use `to_char()`:

```
to_char(to_date(col, 'j'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am a bit confused on 'j'. Could you please elaborate that part?

Comment: @botdeveloper: `j` is the format model for julian dates. See [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) for more information (search for "Julian" in the page).

Comment: Thanks... I understand it works in Oracle. Seems like it is not working on SIlverLake DB.

Comment: Is this an Oracle or Silverlake question?